# I want to do some sync operation in the background using WorkManager. There are many asynchronous call one after another. How to achieve it?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-service, android-workmanager

The doWork() method returns the Result before completing the task, resulting in blocking the main thread.

Some of the answers to this question are: To make the thread wait until the task is completed.
I feel there could be a better way to handle it.

```
class CloudWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, workerParams) {
    val fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    @SuppressLint("LogNotTimber")
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.i("thred_dowork"," :"+Thread.currentThread().name)
        val appContext = applicationContext
        val dataString = inputData.getString(KEY_NOTE_DATA)
        val data = Gson().fromJson(dataString, NoteData::class.java)
        makeStatusNotification("Uploading Notes", appContext)
        Log.i("uri:"," ${data.uri}")

        val resolver = appContext.contentResolver

        appContext.grantUriPermission(appContext.packageName,
            Uri.parse(data.uri),
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        )


        val f = File(data.uri, "profile.jpg")
        val picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileInputStream(f))
        // Create a storage reference from our app
        val storage = Firebase.storage
        // Create a storage reference from our app
        val storageRef = storage.reference

        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
        val imageDataX: ByteArray = baos.toByteArray()

        var pathX = "images/"+System.currentTimeMillis().toString()+".jpg"
        val mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child(pathX)
        val uploadTask = mountainImagesRef.putBytes(imageDataX)
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.i("sync_","Image uploaded"+ it.metadata!!.path+"   :  "+it.metadata!!.name)
            data.uri= it.metadata!!.path
            fireStore.collection("notes")
                .add(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.i("sync_","Sync Succes")
                    if(isStopped)
                        Log.i("sync_","Worker Stopped")
                    else
                        saveUrl()

                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.i("sync_","Sync Succes")
                }
        }.addOnFailureListener{
            Log.e("sync_","Image not uploaded"+it.toString())
        }
        Timber.i("sync_data: $dataString")
        
        Log.i("sync_","Called before firestore"+dataString)
        return Result.success()

    }

    private fun saveUrl() {
        Log.i("sync_","sleeping for 10 sec. thread_ "+Thread.currentThread().name)
        sleep(15000)
        if(isStopped)
            Log.i("sync_","Worker Stopped")
        else
            Log.i("sync_","Worker not stopped")
        Log.i("sync_","Wake up after 10 sec")
        fireStore.collection("employee")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    for (document in task.result!!) {
                        Log.d("sync_employ", document.id + " => " + document.data)
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w("sync_", "Error getting documents.", task.exception)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Here I am doing firebase operation.

1. uploading image to firebase file storage
2. After successful upload, uploading content to the database.
3. On successful upload, retrieving some data from the database.

Your suggestions are most welcome here.

Comment: You either choose to block the worker thread until all the work is complete, or return a ListenableFuture that indicates when the work is done.  These are your two options with WorkManager.

Comment: You can block each task using `Tasks.await()` rather than adding the callbacks to each `Task<T>` object if you require multiple synchronous calls on the current `Thread` - more info : https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/Tasks